# first background image on a website loads slowly

Tags: html, image

The first background image I have on my website - loads slowly.
Now, it's a background image but it should fit a large screen so it's a 900K png.

What are the tricks I can make in order for it to load faster? (it's the first thing you see so even the 3-4 seconds it takes is felt...

Comment: Try using http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ to see what is really taking the longest time.

Comment: optimize your image https://compressor.io/compress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of tricks. The lads above in their comments are right, there are things you can do to compress it, and analysis what is taking the time.

Load times and improving them are around 3 components: 
- Network Latency (the time it takes to pass data from the browser to your host)
- Image Size (physical size of the image that goes down the pipe)
- Connection Cost (Time taken to establish the connection with the host)

Now, if you we take your scenario, you have an image that is large, but not huge. So how can we make it faster, well we can remove the time it takes to download by:

a) compressing it - many options here, along with the google one above, here is a simple one: https://tinypng.com/

b) remove the network latency by ensuring the host sends the cache-control with a max-age in it. This will mean when you refresh it the host returns a 304 and that browser shows the image from the cache

c) use a CDN such as cloudflare to do the hard stuff for you. A CDN will handle the compression, setting of the cache flag, reduce your network latency and ensures your connections are established quickly. Some like cloudflare have free starting tariffs, so worth a look.

d) lazy load the image using javascript after the page has rendered. It's still good to do all the above, but if you create some javascript to fire on document.ready and set the background using css/img tag, background or whatever mechanism you are currently using then it will start the download of the image at that point, enabling your users to see the page and interact with it ahead of your background being finalised.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. Maybe I was misunderstood. The site is back online media.letsfeedme.com/about
It is functional before the image loads - but it's not nice to see an image load slowly 90s style. Tried tinypng - it make only a 800k - still a lot.
The second load is faster (becuase of caching)

Comment: you could consider a CDN like cloudflare as you are wasting 700ms (on my wifi) making a connection to media.letsfeedme.com. Having a CDN in front of your site will speed it up lots. Also, any compression is going to help. Your biggest images is the newyork_bg.png. One thing to remember is that you are only able to open a limited number of connections at one time. If you combined all your JS files into one they would start the download of the images faster.

Comment: Your newyork image is 1.4mb and your total page is 5mb, this is large for a webpage. You might want to consider using something like jpegs or if you want snappy, then webp (google's compressor). The 1.4mb becomes 400kb in webp without lose. You will need to test all the browsers you are going to support support the format thoughL http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-webp

Comment: Oh, by the way the 90s style loading is called progressive image rendering, and you can turn if off. This is part of the interlacing options that have been enabled in the image. Resample the image in a different format or change your options. Interlacing adds to file size.

Answer (score 2):

Besides improving website performance, I consider it an important courtesy to site visitors to make a point of compressing *all* images.

<sup>*(Not to insult anyone's intelligence here but, just to clarify, compressing an image is **not** the same as "shrinking" it's width/height — although both will reduce file size.)*</sup>

If you have 1000 visitors and your site has 100 images and you save a half second of load time per image, then you just saved mankind 14 hours of page load time! (and it only takes a few seconds to compress an image.)

I compress the occasional "one-off" **manually** with:

- [TinyPNG.com](https://tinypng.com/) for `.png`s and `.jpg`'s (up to 20 images at a time)
- [ezGIF.com](https://ezgif.com/optimize) for animated `.GIF`s.

Batches of images can be compressed **programmatically** using a library like:

- [pngquant](https://pngquant.org/), or
- PHP's built-in [ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecompressionquality.php).

As far as I know these all use the same compression algorithm, known as ["Lossy Compression"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression), which can reduce filesize significantly without any noticeable degradation of image quality.